# How to encode or convert a NSData object

Tags: objective-c, ascii, nsdata

I'm developing an iOS app in Objective-C, which is using a [UniMag card reader](http://www.idtechproducts.com/products/mobile-readers/112.html) which can read Magnetic Stripe Reader. I'm using their SDK. When I scan a card, I receive a NSData object which is encoded in standard ASCII.

Unfortunately, I'm scanning a Danish Medical Card which seems to be encoded in different ASCII, possible `ISO/IEC 646:1991 Norwegian/Danish`:
http://www.ascii.ca/iso646.no.htm

For instance, when the persons name on the Medical Card contains a `Ø`, it is displayed as `\`. This is because the encoding used on the card is using decimal 92 for Ø (see the above link), whereas the standard ASCII decimal 92 evaluates to the char `\`. Because of this, I cannot read names if it contains special chars like Æ, Ø and Å.

My question is; how can I convert/encode the NSData object to the right format?

Comment: How do you display the NSData object ?

Comment: Currently both in the console using NSLog and in a UITextField.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, ISO 646 does not provide a single definition for each character. It represents 7-bit ASCII characters, and there are certain ranges in the character set that are defined using region-specific variants. See [the ISO 6464 Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_646) for more information.

As a result, there is probably no specific way to handle this generically so that it will work   correctly in any region. I'm not familiar with the card standards, but it would be interesting to know if there are specific bytes in the card's data that tell you which variant to apply. In other words, is there some bit of information you can read that will tell you whether to apply English, German, Danish, or some other variant?

Once you know which variant to apply, your best bet is probably to look for C libraries that support converting this data into ISO 8859-1. Once you have the data in an ISO-8859-1 (or similar) format you can convert it to an NSString using kCFStringEncodingISOLatin1.

I'm not sure if there are any ISO-646 to ISO-8859-1 conversion libraries available on iOS. The  most common C libraries I've seen out there for this kind of thing is the [libiconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) GNU library, but I don't think there's a specific conversion for your case supported on iOS. If it comes down to it, it shouldn't be too hard to manually convert bytes using the conversion tables shown on on this [man page](http://cims.nyu.edu/cgi-systems/man.cgi?section=5&topic=iconv_646). As you can see, there's only a small number of characters that need to be converted for any given variant.

Answer (score 0):

try to use NSString -initWithBytes:length:encoding:

Comment: So I should convert my NSData object to an byte array? Which encoding should I use?

Comment: a better one [[NSString alloc] initWithData:nsdata encoding: with one of the following:
kCFStringEncodingMacRoman
kCFStringEncodingWindowsLatin1
kCFStringEncodingISOLatin1
kCFStringEncodingNextStepLatin
kCFStringEncodingASCII
kCFStringEncodingUnicode
kCFStringEncodingUTF8
kCFStringEncodingNonLossyASCII, not sure which one can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`[NSString stringWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`

Comment: I've tried with same result. In UTF8 decimal 92 is also evaluating to backspace.